# passing button control to http post method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

hi
I have a actionresult index method in my controller and a http post method for the same name. when i run the program the control should go to the http post method but by default it goes to the index method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //code goes here
}

 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: could you please supply some code from your view/form as well?

Answer (score 1):

By default it will go to the Index method. If you want to call the [HttpPost] Index method you have to call it from a form, e.g.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index")) 
{ %>
    <input type="text" name="someField" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% } %>
```

or using Ajax.BeginForm with the AjaxOption HttpMethod set to "POST"